# MCMC when there are only has minor variations in likelihood

Tags: mcmc

When implementing MCMC the resulting likelihood change when altering parameters is small and so the acceptance rate is very high. How is it possible to cope with this?

I have tried altering the standard deviation for accepting point but this does not work as any points within the range of possible parameter values all cause similar likelihoods and hence acceptance. Expanding the range of possible value for the parameters is undesirable.

For example the range of a parameter could be 0 to 1 and would produce a log-likelihood ranging from -10.6 to -11.2. Taking the two extremes the acceptance ratio would be,

exp(-10.6 - -11.2)=0.5488.

Due to this the vast majority of points are being accepted. Is there some method by which this can be overcome for cases when working with gibbs sampling for 3 parameters?